# How to start the Fluid Framework Server with minimum requirements?

Tags: fluid-framework

I followed the instructions on https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/tree/main/server.
I am having trouble starting the Routerlicious server.

Now I want to bring up a server with minimum requirements.

1. Start Ordering
2. Start Broadcast
3. And store all data in Mongodb

How can I do it?

Comment: There are instructions for running Routerlicious using Docker in [the Routerlicious readme](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/main/server/routerlicious/README.md). Are you seeing a specific error?